# How can I preview Excel files in-browser with Django and Python?

Tags: javascript, python, django, excel

I am trying to view an excel file in browser.

No editing is necessary, the users will just need to preview the files.

I already have a working system for pdf, where my Django server opens the file in a new tab, but when I run the code for an excel file, it downloads the code rather, which isn't ideal, since I don't want to get licenses for all computers accessing the files.

What are my options here?

View.py

```
res = download(token, path)

with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(res.content)
with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
    res = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type=res.headers['Content-Type'])
```

This is the Python-Django code that opens the file. Again, works great for previewing PDF, but I need to preview Excel/Docs files as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can open existing Excel, PDF, and DOCX files in a browser using BytesIO with Django

To open docx, first install python-docx via pip

```
python3 -m pip install python-docx
```

if you using Windows replace "python3" with "py"

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from io import BytesIO
from docx import Document

def open_docx(request):
    # Read the DOCX file and store the contents in BytesIO
    doc = Document('path/to/docx/file.docx')
    buffer = BytesIO()
    doc.save(buffer)
    buffer.seek(0)

    # Determine the content type for DOCX files
    content_type = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'

    # Create the HttpResponse and return it
    response = HttpResponse(buffer, content_type=content_type)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="file.docx"'
    return response
```

To open excel, first install openpyxl

```
python3 -m pip install openpyxl
```

views.py

```
import openpyxl
from django.http import HttpResponse
from io import BytesIO

def open_excel(request):
    # Read the Excel file and store the contents in BytesIO
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('path/to/excel/file.xlsx')
    buffer = BytesIO()
    wb.save(buffer)
    buffer.seek(0)

    # Determine the content type for Excel files
    content_type = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'

    # Create the HttpResponse and return it
    response = HttpResponse(buffer, content_type=content_type)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="file.xlsx"'
    return response
```

To open pdf

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from io import BytesIO

def open_pdf(request):
    # Read the PDF file and store the contents in BytesIO
    with open('path/to/pdf/file.pdf', 'rb') as file:
        file_data = file.read()

    buffer = BytesIO()
    buffer.write(file_data)
    buffer.seek(0)

    # Determine the content type for PDF files
    content_type = 'application/pdf'

    # Create the HttpResponse and return it
    response = HttpResponse(buffer, content_type=content_type)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="file.pdf"'
    return response
```

By using HttpResponse instead of FileResponse and setting Content-Disposition to 'inline', the browser will attempt to display the file instead of downloading it. I hope this help.